# How to load image file inline in MERN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to load image from file inline cuz I have to pass data (the image name) but nothing works, nor if the image is inside src folder, nor if it's outside in public folder

Here is what I tried last:

```
<img src={require(`./styles/images/${image}`).default} alt="product img" />
```

the server returns:

> Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

import logo from './logo.png';

```
<img src={logo} alt="logo" />
```

Comment: I have to pass the image name like that, see my updated question